# при попытке запуска программы вылазит ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'

Tags: python, aiogram

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Константин\Desktop\glazboga\main.py", line 4, in 
from aiogram import Bot, executor, Dispatcher, types
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\Константин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiogram_*init*_.py)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/#simple-usage

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас установлена третья версия, код написан для второй

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v "aiogram==2.23.1"
```

Или импортируй с

```
from aiogram.utils import executor
```